# Calling custom Python COM object from VBA

Tags: python, vba, com

I have a python script which i converted into a COM server. Now i want to call it from VBA (Access).

I have tried this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim PyScript
    Dim var

    Set PyScript = CreateObject("PythonDemos.CodeScript")    
    var = PyScript.CodeReader()    
    Debug.Print var    
End Sub
```

But i get an error at CreateObject(...):
        Automation error 2147024770

From what i read this means that the module "PythonDemos" can not be found.

Here is the python code:

```
class Main:
    _public_methods_ = ['CodeReader']
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.CodeScript"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{B74B241B-0699-4332-8145-145512D332D1}"

    def CodeReader(self, item=None):
        #do stuff here and return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Main)
```

It runs well on its own and was registered without problems as COM server.

My Question is: How to call this python script correctly from vba? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error I got it to work. The syntax in VBA was correct, but i updated the Python script. I am not sure, but i think the

```
pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
```

did the trick. I was just a little confused because PyCharm told me that it is not a valid command. Just ignored that and expanded the header like this

```
class Main:
    _reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    _reg_clsid_ = "{F223CC90-AB60-442C-BE81-C79701C47059}" 
    _reg_desc_ = "Python Code Reader"
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.CodeScript"
    _public_methods_ = ['CodeReader', 'test']
    _readonly_attrs_ = []
    _public_attrs_ = []


    def test(self):
        return "Test Erfolgreich"


    def CodeReader(self):
        #calculate and return stuff...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, 'importers'):
        if '--register' in sys.argv[1:] or '--unregister' in sys.argv[1:]:
            win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Main)
        else:
            from win32com.server import localserver
            localserver.serve('{F223CC90-AB60-442C-BE81-C79701C47059}')
    else:
        win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Main)
```

I can't yet say if the code at the bottom is working like it is supposed to for an .exe file but for the .py file it is.

Comment: in 2023, i get NameError: name 'pythoncom' is not defined.  This would be with Python 3.6.