# Exposing a Python Class to COM/VBA

Tags: python, vba, com

I have a simple python class that I am trying to make com-accessible (e.g., to VBA):

```
class Foo(object):
    _reg_progid_ = 'Foo.Application'
    _reg_clsid_ = '{602462c5-e750-4d1c-879b-a0465bebb526}'
    _public_methods_ = ['say_hello']

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(self, name):
        return f'Hello, {name}'


if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Registering COM server")
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Foo)
```

Several examples indicate this is a pretty standard approach (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975659/portable-python-com-server-using-pywin32/42208612#42208612) and [here](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2019/01/vba-python-best-option-for-microsoft.html)).

From python, this appears to be com-accessible. No errors raise, and the output appears as expected:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
f = CreateObject('Foo.Application')
f.say_hello('David')
```

When trying to instantiate a `Foo` from VBA, however, there is an error (*Run-time error -2147024770 (8007007e) Automation error The specified module could not be found*).

```vb
Dim f As Object
Set f = CreateObject("Foo.Application")
```

[image: Run-time error -2147024770 (8007007e) Automation error The specified module could not be found]

**I am actually able to resolve this error** using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567064/calling-com-object-from-vba) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054849/consuming-python-com-server-from-net/1054986#1054986)), specifically doing:

```
_reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
```

And then `localserver.serve('{602462c5-e750-4d1c-879b-a0465bebb526}')` in the name guard function.

However, in some past applications development work (a long time ago using python 2.7) I know we did not do this part -- instead  we used Innosetup to compile an installer from a `foo.exe` and `foo.dll` (derived from `foo.py` probably from py2exe or similar) and other dependencies.

I'm happy (for now) with the solution, but I guess my question is whether this is necessary (as several examples don't do these things) or if there's something else I'm missing (e.g., the installer that I used in a past life actually handled this bit behind-the-scenes with the DLL instead of a .py file?)?

Additional information: OS is 64-bit Windows, running Excel 2013 (32-bit) and python 3.7.4 (32-bit).